# Why error "Access Denied" when creating a adhoc report in JasperReports Server?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

When adding new users to the JasperReports Server (v6.2), everything works fine.

The new user

- can use predefined adhoc reports
- can use predefined reports
- is able to change predefined reports

But if the user tries to create a new adhoc report, he gets an error `Access is denied`. Unfortunately the error message (it is a very long log) doesn't show to *which* component or folder the access is denied.

What I tried so far:

- Recreating the user
- Changing rights for the `Domain` (tried `Read-Only` / `Execute-Only`)
- Checked folder structure if rights are set correctly (they appear to be correct)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there has been a change in the required rights for the `Data Source` from version 6.0.x on (comment [from here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/847936/accessdeniedexception-after-js-upgrade-55-aws-601-aws)):

> Appears to be a regression in 6.0.1 and at least a Read-Only permission on a Data Source is now required,
>   while Execute-Only was sufficient in 5.5.

The adhoc creation works without a problem now.